# Automapper: "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I got an `User` and a `UserListDto`. I'm trying to map my `User` to `UserListDto`.

However I'm getting an,

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

**It works when I call `GetUsers()` but not `GetUser(int id)`**

UsersController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers()
    {
        var users = await _repo.GetUsers();

        var usersToReturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserForListDto>>(users);

        return Ok(usersToReturn);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetUser")]
    public IActionResult GetUser(int id)
    {
        var user = _repo.GetUser(id, false);

        var userToReturn = _mapper.Map<UserForListDto>(user);

        return Ok(userToReturn);
    }
```

AutoMapperProfiles:

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserForListDto>();
        CreateMap<User, UserForDetailedDto>();
        CreateMap<UserForRegisterDto, User>();
        CreateMap<HighScoreDto, HighScore>()
        .ForMember(h=>h.TimeBetweenClicksAverage, 
        m=>m.MapFrom(u=>u.TimeBetweenClicksArray.Average()));
        CreateMap<HighScore,HighScoreForReturnDto>();



    }
}
```

User:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HighScore> HighScores { get; set; }
}
```

UserForDetailedDto:

```
public class UserForDetailedDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Look at the full error message. It's telling you exactly what map you're missing.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu here is the error https://www.codepile.net/pile/eLv3JbAk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are two problems: 1) you're not `await`ing the call to `_repo.GetUser` and 2) you're trying to map a single `User` to an `IEnumerable<UserForListDto>`.

Make sure you `await _repo.GetUser` and then `_mapper.Map<UserForListDto>(user)`

Since you're not awaiting the repo call, it's trying to map a type `Task` to `UserListDto`, which is not a configured mapping.

Comment: The problem was "1) you're not awaiting the call to _repo.GetUser"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be trying to map a single User object to an IEnumerable collection. In your GetUser(int id) method, try mapping it to a single UserForListDto object this way:

`_mapper.Map<UserForListDto>(user)`

Comment: Is your _repo.GetUser(id, false) method async? In your error message it looks like it is trying to map a Task<User> instead of a User object. You might just need to make  your GetUser(int id) controller method async and await the _repo.GetUser(id, false) method.